# How do I print the exception stack trace

Tags: java, exception

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class multicatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Throwable t = new Exception("Tis is some kind of throwable exception");  
            PrintWriter ps=new PrintWriter("D:\\fff.txt");
  t.printStackTrace(ps);
    }
}
```

This program creates "fff.txt" and it prints nothing in that file.

Comment: Did you got any error or exception in console..

Comment: no errors...build successfully

Comment: Write one more line t.printStackTrace(); before t.printstacktrace(PS);

Comment: This will write the exception if any into console

Comment: do u know any good tutorial for exception handling...

Comment: Wait for a minute...

Comment: yes it shows in console , but i want it to write in that text file

Comment: just wait for 2 mins I correct your code..

Comment: simply add `ps.flush()` as last statement or close the stream which will automatically flush the stream.

Comment: yes ur right ,it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
  public class multicatch {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Throwable t = new Exception("This is some kind of throwable exception");  
        PrintWriter ps=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("F:\\fff.txt", true));
    ps.write(t.getMessage());

        ps.close();
  }      
 }
```

Comment: @simonasir Change F:\\ in  my code to D:\\ as your file location path.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the PrintWriter at the end.

```
ps.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class throwexception {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Throwable t = new Exception("Throwable exception");  
            PrintWriter ps=new PrintWriter("D:\\fff.txt");
            t.printStackTrace();
  t.printStackTrace(ps);
  ps.close();
    }
}
```

need to close the stream...

Answer (score -1):

**catch** the **exception** in which you are interested in with a **try**

```
try{ //...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(yourOutputStream));
    //or
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Note that is possible to redirect the stack trace to the output stream you want.

Comment: You don't need to throw and catch it first.